# Send_email with django generate error _getfullpathname:

Tags: python, django, email

i'm tring to send email with django but i recive ad error even with a easy code

```
send_mail(
            'Subject here',
            'Here is the message.',
            'from@example.com',
            ['to@example.com'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
```

i get that output error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\VisualStudioWorkspaces\DjangoPlayground\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\VisualStudioWorkspaces\DjangoPlayground\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\VisualStudioWorkspaces\DjangoPlayground\django_tutorial\accounts\views.py", line 93, in register
    send_mail(
  File "D:\VisualStudioWorkspaces\DjangoPlayground\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 52, in send_mail
    connection = connection or get_connection(
  File "D:\VisualStudioWorkspaces\DjangoPlayground\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 35, in get_connection
    return klass(fail_silently=fail_silently, **kwds)
  File "D:\VisualStudioWorkspaces\DjangoPlayground\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\filebased.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.file_path = os.path.abspath(self.file_path)
  File "C:\Users\oscur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ntpath.py", line 527, in abspath
    return normpath(_getfullpathname(path))

Exception Type: TypeError at /accounts/registration/
Exception Value: _getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not NoneType
```

Comment: What is your `EMAIL_BACKEND` in settings.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django support different email backends.

1. SMTP backend(Default)
2. Console backend
3. File backend
4. In-memory backend

When you use `send_mail` function without a backend argument  django select [backend based on `settings.EMAIL_BACKEND`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/core/mail/__init__.py#L34).

From the exception it seems like   [django using File backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/#file-backend)(Which means `EMAIL_BACKEND` you are using most likely `'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend'`)

Quoting from the django docs

> The file backend writes emails to a file. A new file is created for
> each new session that is opened on this backend. The directory to
> which the files are written is **either taken from the EMAIL_FILE_PATH**
> setting or from the file_path keyword when creating a connection with
> get_connection().

So my suggestion is that setting `EMAIL_FILE_PATH` in settings.py will solve this issue.